Kendo Drag And Drop between Two Components in Angular..Is It Possible?
Drag right side component Parameters to drop in Email body component
1: https://i.sstatic.net/OkRseP18.png*strong text*
hi Guys,
i have two components emailBody Component and PaarametersComponent..I need to drag the parameters from Parameter cOmponent ro Email Body Component that is kendo Editor ..I use previously drag and drop in one component..so Iam confused that how achieve Kendo drag and drop between to components in angular..
